# Why is this flexbox layout broken in Safari?

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

So I designed this in CSS, the idea is to have a header and the rest as scrollable content.
(there's a link to a **live demo** at the bottom)

[image: Layout as seen in chrome]

Alas, in Safari it is broken and looks like this:
[image: Layout in Safari]

As you can see, the height of the header is miscalculated, causing the green box to overflow.

I narrowed down the problem to a wrong calculation of `flex-basis` of the header. Or so I believe.

Live demo here: **http://jsbin.com/zusavefoqu**

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to add vendor prefixes.

Currently, flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

---

Also, it seems like there are two problems with your layout in Safari:

- the header overflow, and
- the vertical scrollbar on `#more` is missing.

For a list of common flex bugs and their workarounds see this page: [**Flexbugs**](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs).

Comment: Thanks, I did use auto prefixing. Forgot to mention it. Simplified for this demo

Comment: Thanks for the link! Although you did not immediately offer the solution, the first issue on the list solved it for me! `flex-shrink: 0`