# Flexbox child element extending beyond bounds of parent only on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, flexbox

This is the structure of the episode box. `display: flex` is applied to the div with the class of episode.

The h2 is not expanding to change its parent's width on Safari? Any reasons why?

Here is the code, simple PostCSS with nesting and auto-prefixing: https://gist.github.com/Connorelsea/897cf41f7b9e43bdce43

[image: episode box]

Rendered on Safari:

[image]

Rendered on Firefox:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34976604/3597276

Comment: Setting flex shrink to 0 on all children sort of fixes it, but then makes the second child element hang off its edge instead of the numbers.

Comment: I'm on mobile so can't really test. Will continue later if nobody else has answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in Safari 10.0.1. Seems this was a bug in older versions of Safari (v9) and how they handle flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that your problem is the Cross-Browser-Support for CSS-Flexbox

Try this (should work in all browsers)

```
.foo {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
   -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
   -webkit-box-direction: normal;
   -moz-box-direction: normal;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   -ms-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
 }
```

(Ofc with the right options)

Comment: Nah this stuff is all already inserted by the auto-prefixer and still doesn't work in Safari with it. But thanks for the suggestion! :)

Comment: I would try it, but I'm not at home...Sry maybe later if you still got no answere